# How to configure Conky to be on one specific viewport/desktop?

Tags: gnome, conky

I would like Conky to only show up on one viewport/desktop.
I did use the Gnome feature to predefine viewports for specific window classes, but this feature does not work for Conky. Even moving it manually to another viewport does not work, because it jumps back to the first viewport, as it refreshes.

So... is it possible to configure Conky to define the viewport it is displayed on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow these simple steps:

1. Look through your conky setup for any references to `own_window_hints`.  If there is a reference to 'sticky', remove it as it will cause conky to draw your window on all workspaces (making this entire exercise a moot point)
2. Look through for references to `own_window_type` as well.  You want this set to 'normal', because it does not enable the 'sticky' from above.  For my money, I personally do not use `own_window_type`, instead preferring to set everything through `own_window_hints` for finer control of the own window settings.
3. Determine the size of each viewport.  This can be done with the `wmctrl` program, which you might need to install first.  The command to install it is:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```

   To use it, type into a command window, `wmctrl -d`.  This will give you the overall size of your combined viewports (DG), the viewport location of your current workspace (VP), and a few other details like the dimensions of your current workspace.
4. Apply a `gap_x` and `gap_y` to match these dimensions for each workspace you want to move your conky window over to. For example, if `wmctrl` is giving you:

   > 0  * DG: 6720x1050  VP: 0,0  WA: 49,24 1631x1026  N/A

then you might want to start with `gap_x` of at least 1631 to start with to get onto the second workspace (in this example you have 4 workspaces of 1631x1026 set side by side in a horizontal arrangement.

From there, obviously tinker away to get it precisely where you want it...and happy Conkying!

[Source](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20151028214930/http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254799)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Edited to provide more data and a backup link to the relevant article via the Internet Archive.  Thank you for pointing out that the link I provided may be considered volatile and just providing a link to that location is not a suitable answer to this question in the longer term (for those that might come across it in the future, needing the answer for themselves).

Comment: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/692739/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**  Oh: I also removed the downvote and added an upvote!  Keep up the good work!

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 0):

A [friendly redditor](http://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/pew12/how_to_configure_conky_to_be_on_one_specific/c3p3agi) answered my question with the following trick:

Set the gap_x and gap_y properties, so that conky is positioned on the wished viewport. Not the nicest solution, but it works for me.